# Find start and end position of "cover-all" path then connect them

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I have the shape in my 2dArray like this (for example):

[image]

It is known that the points A and B (I do not know where) and a path that covers the entire shape (must walk through each cell) must exist. Can you give me some help on how to determine points A and B and then the "cover-all" path? Maybe there are some known algorithms for such case. Or some help with a pseudo-code algorithm. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What function do you want.. It is not clear.. You want an algorithm to find the start positon, and endposition, and path between them?

Comment: the path you drew does not go through the upper right cell, is this on purpose?

Comment: It appears he wants a path that will cover all gray tiles, with the start and end points at the algorithm's discretion.

Comment: you have poor eyesight, all grey cells was included in path

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem You can reduce the size of the graph by collapsing cells with exactly 2 neighbors.

Comment: @nhatch Agree. I deleted my answer

Comment: Is the solution guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @maniek: It is clear from the question that it may not be unique (There are 2 possibility for B).

Comment: @nhahtdh Won't collapsing 2-neighbor nodes give an incomplete solution if done ahead of time? For instance, in the picture above, collapsing the two B points and the adjacent cell above/right of them will not give both B endpoints. I imagine it only works for directed paths, such as the single-exit grouping near A.

Comment: @Maple: You are right. (Actually, I don't know if re-expanding the node afterwards will work - not sure if it interferes with the result).

Comment: What are the maximum sizes that takes each dimension in the worst case? Any particular complexity for the solution in particular? You can use brute force, but it depends of the answers of my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Check `nhahdth`'s link to see that your problem in general is np-hard. [this mathoverflow article](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36368/efficient-way-to-count-hamiltonian-paths-in-a-grid-graph-for-a-given-pair-of-ver) cites a [paper](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf) establishing the result for graphs on grids with holes - you won't fare significantly better than using brute force unless you can come up with more constraints.

You may be lucky in identifying at least one of your start and end nodes by searching for vertices of degree 1 in the underlying grid cell graph.